# How to process response from Stripe

Tags: c#, json.net, stripe-payments, httphandler

I am making a payment to the Stripe gateway which returns as a successful payment.

I have setup the CLI to listen and forward the response to my localhost handler.

I have the below code in my Handler

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var reques = context.Request;
    }
```

However when the successful response comes back in, the breakpoint is hit and i analyse it. Im looking for a JSON response but i cant seem to find anything related to the feedback of this transaction. Nothing in Response, nothing in reques.Form.

How do i retrieve the response to take action for database related tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up a [Stripe webhook](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks). The bottom of this page contains some next steps. Additionally, the Dashboard has a section under Developer for managing [webhooks](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks).

By using a webhook, you can let Stripe ***call you*** with all sorts of event types. For example, after a charge you can receive notification of the pending charge and  success (usually milliseconds behind). This is also a good way to learn of disputes being opened.

These messages will have the JSON you are looking for. Your handler can then take action on your database.